# Build delphi project in jenkins

Tags: delphi, jenkins, continuous-integration, components

Im trying to setup jenkins in my company and Ive got some problems. 
Im using this commands to build the project:

```
SET MSBuild="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe"
SET BUILDS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\xxx\builds\
SET OUTPUT_PATH="%BUILDS%%BUILD_NUMBER%"
SET RSVARS="C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0\bin\rsvars.bat"
CALL %RSVARS%
SET PATH=%PATH%;D:\komponenty\DXE3\ADSI
%MSBuild% xxx.dproj /t:Build /p:Config=Debug;Platform=Win32;DCC_ExeOutput=%OUTPUT_PATH% /maxcpucount:4
```

It works fine when i type this in cmd but. I gave administrive privileges to jenkins service. When I try to build project with jenkins i receive error like this:

```
F1026: File not found: 'ADSI.dcu
```

this is a component for Delphi and i have this component on second partition. Jenkins has access for many components on this partition but not for this one.

Comment: You are using search paths. How are these setup? I personally always feel that search paths leave you unsure at to which version of a file is being built. I always include all source files in the dpr and then I know what I'm building. Then I don't need any search paths. All you do is check out from vcs and the source is all under that tree.

Comment: Perhaps perform a search to find where the file `ADSI.dcu` is located.  It may be that when building from the command-line you are picking up a different file from that which you expect.  That could be informative. I would also recommend outputting `.dcus` to a single folder, and I concur with David's comment; it can save a load of grief if your coders are building to the same standards as your build.

Comment: I presume `D:\komponenty\DXE3\ADSI` is where your project source is located? It's not a good idea to add to your PATH environment variable. Rather just ensure you're in the correct working folder to do you build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two will be your current directory.
Jenkins will start you off in a specific working folder for the job (possibly `C:\Users\<User-ID>\.jenkins\jobs\<Job-Name>\workspace`).

Add the following to your Jenkins commands to see where you're doing the build from:

```
echo Current Folder: %cd%
```

A simple "solution" would be to just add a command in Jenkins to change directory to the same folder you're in when you test from the command-line.

However, I suggest you rather do the following:

- Ensure Jenkins gets the latest source from your source repository into its working folder. (There are various plugins depending on what particular tool you use.)
- Ensure you `cd` (change directory) to the correct folder within the workspace folder.